# How to distinguish between published and unpublished Comments/Replies v3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to distinguish between comments that are already approved and published and comments that are not yet approved?

I have a video where the option that only approved comments are shown.
Now i call the commentThreads route in the youtube v3 data api with the option moderationStatus = heldForReview
I now get all comments that are held for review and waiting for approval as well as all comments that are already approved but have at least one reply that is not.

My problem is that I found no way to distinguish between both.